# Echo from foreach

Tags: codeigniter

i have model that return

```
return array(
        'senin'=> $senin->result(),
        'selasa'=> $selasa->result(),
        'rabu'=> $rabu->result()


    );
```

and controller

```
$data['ot'] = $this->genbamodel->getOt();
```

in my view, i use 'foreach $ot as key' and when i tried to print_r($key) the result like this

`Array()
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id_genba] => 1 [hari] => Tuesday [shift1] => 2 [shift2] => 0 ))
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id_genba] => 1 [hari] => Wednesday [shift1] => 1 [shift2] => 2 ))`

how to get just shift1 = 2 and shift2 = 0 (from second array / hari=>Tuesday ??
Thankyou

Comment: it give me error Message: Undefined offset: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the foreach loop to access those values. To get just the second record, you can do the below.

```
$ot['selasa'][0]->shift1
$ot['selasa'][0]->shift2    
$ot['selasa'][0]->hari
```

Comment: yes i have tried this just a second before reading your answer and it's work sir. thankyou so much for help